# get promise from async function from non-async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication

So My problem is that when Im verifying the users credentials, the promise from login() will not have been resolved yet. So the loginResult will be Promise{}. I know I need to await the result some how but I just can think of anyway.

Any tips appreciated. This is for a school project so please dont berate me on how unsecure this is.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var login = require('../controller/authenticate/login');

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

/* Login user */
router.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
  const username = req.body.username;

  // This is a async return so its not working right. Currently only reading Promise{<pending>}
  let loginResult = login(username, req.body.password);

  console.log(loginResult)
  if (loginResult === true) {
    res.render('users', {username: username});
  }
  else {
    res.render('index', {error: true});
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

Add `async` in front of your function then `await`:

```js
router.post('/login', async function (req, res, next) {
  const username = req.body.username;

  const loginResult = await login(username, req.body.password);

  console.log(loginResult)

  if (loginResult === true) {
    res.render('users', {username: username});
  } else {
    res.render('index', {error: true});
  }
});
```

Or use Promises and `then`:

```js
router.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
  const username = req.body.username;

  login(username, req.body.password)
    .then(resp => {
      console.log(resp)
      if (resp === true) {
        res.render('users', {username: username});
      } else {
        res.render('index', {error: true});
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: LMAO, thank you! Going with the first since its most similar to my other code.